# Грамматическая основа предложения в задании

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении: "Однако существуют люди, которые имеют феноменaльную пaмять" - авторами выделена основа "которые имеют память". Я с ними категорически не согласен, поскольку "которые имеют" уже само по себе достаточно для смысловой организации предложении. Память я бы разобрал как дополнение. Что вы на этот счет думаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Однако существуют люди, **которые имеют** феноменальную память.*

Здесь основа, как я думаю, ***которые имеют***.

**Пояснение**

Можно посмотреть в [толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

**ИМЕТЬ**,  нсв. 1. что. Владеть чем-л. на правах собственности. И. машину. И. дачу. И. большую библиотеку. И. дом в деревне. И. много денег. 2. **кого-что.** **Обладать, располагать** кем-, чем-л. Друзей надежных я имею. Она не может и. детей. И. опыт в чём-л. **Он имеет прекрасный слух**. И  т.д.

У глагола ***иметь*** сильное управление: это **переходный** глагол, которому для выражения смысла требуется **прямое дополнение.** Поэтому может показаться, что здесь неразложимое сочетание, но это не так.

В то же время в словаре отдельно указаны **устойчивые словосочетания** с глаголом *иметь*, которые будут рассматриваться как один член предложения.

**Иметь виды** на кого-что (см. 1. Вид). **Иметь голову на плечах** (см. Голова). **Иметь дело** с кем-чем (см. Дело). **Иметь место**. Быть, происходить, совершаться. И т.д.

2. Дополнением будет скорее всё сочетание ***феноменальную память***, так как в сочетании ***иметь память*** нет смысла (все люди имеют память, но не все феноменальную).

В **нечленимом сочетании** слово нельзя убрать без нарушения смысла предложения.

Comment: Но ведь без "память " не будет законченного смысла.: "Они имеют. . . " Почему тогда нельзя рассмотреть это сочетание как единое целое?